# Identify the Git client of Git Commit

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Project uses different Git clients to commit the code like Git Bash, Tortoise Git and Eclipse.

I would like to identify the commits from made from each Git client. 
Does there any way to identify whether the commit is made from Git BASH, or TOrtoise GIT or Eclipse.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to be able to identify the git client on a per-commit basis?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, unless you add some prefix to each commit depending on which tool they use.

I now you did not ask for this, but you can monitor the user IP that is pushing by implementing a git hook or depending on what git-server you are using, there must be some logs there you could scan. The commits themselves track the user name and email address.